# Guzzle curl error 51 in PHPUnit context

Tags: laravel, ssl, curl, phpunit, guzzle

I have a Laravel app that uses a web service to validate a field, the REST call goes through Guzzle over HTTPS. When I post a form through the browser, everything goes fine. When I run the same through phpunit as a test, Guzzle fails with:

`exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 51: SSL: certificate verification failed (result: 5)`

**What I tried:**

1- Before Guzzle I used straight up curl which gave the same behaviour. I tried setting the cacert explicitly in the code with `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cacert.pem');` and that did nothing

2- I tried (same result) pointing Guzzle to the cacert with

```
$response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
    'auth' => ['user', 'pass'],
    'verify' => '/path/to/cacert.pem'
]);
```

3- phpinfo says Apache is using its local curl and command line php uses a different one so I symlinked to the Apache version, same result

4- Both curl.cainfo and openssl.cainfo are set

5- `/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem` exists

6- passing `-d openssl.cainfo` to phpunit on the command line does nothing

**Code:**

```
private function curl_rest_call($url){

    // $curl = curl_init() ;

    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pass");

    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/to/cacert.pem');

    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // $rest = curl_exec($curl);
    // $httpStatus = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    // curl_close($curl);
    // $result = json_decode($rest) ;

    // $result->status = $httpStatus ;

    // return $result ;

    $client = new Guzzle();
    $response = $client->request('GET', $url, [
        'auth' => ['user', 'pass'],
        'verify' => '/path/to/cacert.pem'
    ]);

    $result = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents()) ;
    $result->status = $response->getStatusCode() ;

    return $result ;

}
```

**Test:**

```
public function testSuccessfulSignup(){

    $this->visit('/free-software')
        ->type('test@mail.com', 'mail')
        ->type('Philip', 'first_name')
        ->type('Fry', 'last_name')
        ->select('Freelancer', 'profile')
        ->type('Other', 'industry')
        ->select('Canada', 'country')
        ->type('(514) 278-8666', 'phone_number')
        ->press('Try Harmony Now!')
        ->seePageIs('/success');
}
```

Comment: Most likely the PEM file you are specifying for the certificate check does not contain the CA cert in use by the site you're connecting to.  Can you confirm it is present in the file?

Comment: @drew010 yep, it's there

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I would probably try to avoid testing actually calling the external service in the first place. Tests like this are usually (very) slow and brittle (e.g. because of connection issues) causing lots of false negatives. Having a functional test that uses a stub-service is much more reliable. You can still test the actual functionality in an acceptance-test e.g. using Selenium-driven interactions with your UI. Just out of curiosity could you post the test?

Comment: @dbrumann the test is very simple, I thought about stubbing the REST call but it's tied to the model validation using a custom validator at the `AppServiceProvider` level.

Comment: Hmm well cURL error 51 means: `The remote server's SSL certificate or SSH md5 fingerprint was deemed not OK.`  Do you get any errors visiting the site in the browser?  What cURL version is PHP using, and also what OpenSSL version is that cURL linked to?

Comment: Oh, this is an acceptance test. Totally not what I was expecting; that makes it more peculiar. I thought it might be some subtle configuration-difference, but that seems highly unlikely in this test. Did you try monitoring the traffic between your app and the API using something like wireshark or Charles Proxy? It would be interesting to see whether the API-calls look different on a request-level when doing it manually and when running the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what the problem was.

I call `phpunit` from the command line and as it's a php script not a binary, that invokes the default system install of php at a different location than the one the webserver is using and so ignores the cacert directive and php.ini config.

While in theory it shouldn't, it completely ignored the `-d openssl.cainfo` switch and the `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable (which curl uses)

In the end I prepended the webserver php version on the `PATH` variable so that calling `phpunit` will load the right cacert info.